# Working around the 16 local variable limit?

Tags: solidity, evm

I have a function which negotiates an agreement between two parties using a state channel, to accomplish this I need two signatures `bytes32 e, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s`x2 for the state channel, and I need some variables for each persons agreement that are signed by the state.

**This results in a stack too deep error**. My workaround is to compress the signatures and variables into a `bytes32[]` array and type cast where needed. This seems dumb. Anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're dealing with repeated data types it's more natural to group them into arrays by type, eg

```
function myThing(bytes32[] es, uint8[] vs, bytes32[] rs, bytes32[] ss)
```

This also tends to reduce code duplication inside the function, as you will only need one line doing `ecrecover`, which you then repeat in a loop.

If you're still short of variables, you may also want to consider breaking part of the functionality out into another function.

Comment: Its a public function that runs as one transaction. I had this thought as well but in this case it was more natural for making `bytes32[]`. Thanks for validating my suspicion that there really is not a much better way

Comment: If the stack-too-deep error is triggered by variables you use inside the function rather than purely by the number of parameters then it may still help to split the functionality up internally.

Comment: Is there a good reason for this limit? Technically it seems totally arbitrary. Like, I can have a dynamic length raw byte variable but I can't have 17 `uint8`s?

Comment: See gory details here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2693