# Passing 13 arguments in function giving error: Stack too deep, try using less variables

Tags: solidity

I am trying to pass 13 arguments as string and creating a structure with them. But I am getting error: Stack too deep, try using less variables.

My code:

```
struct Test { 
// 13 string variables... }

function myfunc(13 string parameters...){
      Test t = Test(13 parameters...); // have to initialize t
}
```

Any possible solution to the problem ?

Comment: Just a friendly remark. When you need 13 parameters for a function, maybe the interface design should be improved. I can't remember a situation where I really needed more than 8 parameters during the past 25 years as a developer (coding in more than a dozen languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code is working perfectly fine:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract multiVar {
    struct trial { 
        string s1;
        string s2;
        string s3;
        string s4;
        string s5;
        string s6;
        string s7;
        string s8;
        string s9;
        string s10;
        string s11;
        string s12;
        string s13;

    }
    trial t;

    function myfunc(string t1,
        string t2,
        string t3,
        string t4,
        string t5,
        string t6,
        string t7,
        string t8,
        string t9,
        string t10,
        string t11,
        string t12,
        string t13){
          t = trial(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13);
    }
}
```

However, you may want to know that there is a limitation on number of local variables you can use. [This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28052/16048) answer might solve your problem.

Comment: This is the code: https://files.fm/u/t9ytn4uj   Can you please review it ?