# My EVM does not support random access to stack

Tags: evm, yellow-paper, stack

EVM supports the following operations that allow access to variables with depth up to 16 on the stack: `DUP1..DUP16`, `SWAP1..SWAP16`.

These do cover most popular use-cases, but it may sometimes lead to problems like [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28050/working-around-the-16-local-variable-limit). Why couldn't the creators of Ethereum add an operation like `SWAPXY` that could take two elements at the top of the stack equal to `X` and `Y` respectively and to swap them? The same goes for `DUP`.

The current limitation is fine for most cases, but the reasoning for the design of EVM is very interesting.

Most EVM implementations implement the stack as some kind of a vector, so it would not affect the existing implementations.